# How to avoid VueJS to remove the props attributes in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a `prop` on a component that is correctly passed to the component. The value is correctly set inside the component. But the attribute is removed at the compilation time of VueJS. (I guess)

How can I avoid the attribute to be removed ? At runtime I need to be able to get every element with same attribute like: `$("[group-name=' + vm.groupName + ']");`

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Elfayer/8xwm9LmL/)

### HTML

```
<script type="x-template" id="my-component-tpl">
  <div>My Component's group name is <b>{{groupName}}</b>.</div>
  <div>But the attribute 'group-name' is no longer in the DOM...</div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component group-name="Demo"></my-component>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var myComponent = {
  template: '#my-component-tpl',
  props: ['groupName']
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-component': myComponent
  }
});
```

Comment: Why would you want it in the dom?

Comment: @gurghet As mentioned in the question : "I need to be able to get every element with same attribute like: `$("[group-name=' + vm.groupName + ']");`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that I personally think you should rather use a class that some non-standard attribute - you will have to addd it to the root element again in the template.

```
<script type="x-template" id="my-component-tpl">
  <div v-bind:group-name="groupName">
    My Component's group name is <b>{{groupName}}, and the outer div also has the correspondign attribute now.</b>
   </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to go for something like this. =/ I cannot use a class, because the element could have any `group-name` and possibly multiple class names. Which would make it difficult to guess which class to use.

Answer (score 1):

I solved your issue. (Implementing what @LinusBorg said)

http://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/8xwm9LmL/1/

On a side-note: Remember that when you set `replace: true` (which is the default, so, if you *don't* set it, you set it to true) you are telling Vue to replace your component, in this case `<my-component>...</my-component>` with your component. If you don't like this behavior, set `replace: false`.

Comment: The `replace` attribute is a good thing to keep in mind, thanks ! Although I believe, in my case anyway, it makes the DOM look a bit broken using components.

Comment: Any documentation on how to use `replace` attribute? I don't know how to use it.